# How to create arrow array of dates using ArrayFromJSON

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

Basically, I want to create array of `date32` type using nice `ArrayFromJSON` function which is super handy for writing unit tests.
I've tried:

```
auto dateArray = arrow::ArrayFromJSON(arrow::date32(), R"(["2017-11-01"])");
```

But this doesn't work at least for arrow version is `1.0`. Could not find something similar in unit tests.

Comment: "this doesn't work" why not? what happens? why is that wrong? please quote any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing date32 from timestamps is not currently supported by `ArayFromJSON`; only the integral values are currently accepted:

```cpp
auto dateArray = arrow::ArrayFromJSON(arrow::date32(), "[17471000]");
```

Alternatively, you could construct a timestamp array then cast to date32 (but this cast may not be supported in your version of arrow):

```cpp
auto tsArray = arrow::ArrayFromJSON(arrow::timestamp(TimeUnit::SECOND),
                                    R"(["2017-11-01"])");
auto dateArray = compute::Cast(*tsArray, arrow::date32()).ValueOrDie();
```